# UITableView touch event

Tags: ios, uitableview, touch

Here's the scenario :

I have a UITableView, and a UITextView, added as subviews on a UIView.
When the user touches on any of the row, I want 2 things - resignFirstResponder for the UITextView and  I want a pop type UIView added for the particular row.

That is done.

But I want the same functionality of resignFirstResponder for the UITextView when the user touches on the region of the tableView where there are no rows.

How to do that, is there any method of tableView, which lets me handle the touches on the region where there are no rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What u ll have to do is, create a custom `UITableView`. (subclassing `UITableView`, by creating a new file)

Override the '`touchesBegan`' method of this custom tableView (which we can do because `UITableView` is a subclass of a `UIView`)

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

     //resignFirstResponder for the UITextView

     //call didSelectRow of tableView again, by passing the touch to the super class
     [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

What we are doing is that, we are overriding how the `UITablView` catches the touch. We can do that in the `touchesBegan` method, as `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIView` itself.

So we can override the `touchesBegan` method, to catch the touch on the `UITableView`, and then pass it further on to the super class of our custom tableView, which is `UITableView`, so that its '`didSelectRow`' method gets called.

Comment: That did work! Awesome.

I still didnt get why we needed the 2nd line, passing the touch to the super.

Comment: Thats because we still want to do something on the selection of the rows. So you must have written that pop-up functionality you mentioned, in the didSelectRow method.
Now to call that, after catching the touch, you again have to pass the touch to the original UITableView (super class of custom tablView)
Try this for understanding. Comment the last line where we are passing the touch to the super class, and see what happens.
Now, only the resignFirstResponder functionality would work, even when u click on the rows.
Hope, that clears up everything.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested but I think you could add a touchevent to the tableview's backgroundView.
You can access the background view with `tableView.backgroundView`

Hope this helps